# Why would ClickOnce app that uses QBFC crash when using a VS test certificate?

Tags: clickonce, code-signing, qbfc

I have an application that I distribute using ClickOnce. I used to sign the manifest with a GoDaddy code signing cert. It expired. I switched to using a VS generated test cert. (It's an internal application so I figured I'd save the money.) Now, when you try to use any functionality that uses QBFC (integration with QuickBooks) the application crashes. (Only when distributed and signed, not in VS while debugging.) I thought signing the ClickOnce manifest was just about verification for installation. If I distribute without signing, it works. When I distributed with the GoDaddy cert, it worked. When I distribute with the VS test cert, it crashes, but only when attempting to use QBFC to talk to QuickBooks. I get no response from anyone on Intuit dev sites. Figured I'd post here to see if anyone can shed any light on what's going on. I suspect I'll have to get a "real" certificate, again, or just go unsigned, but I was hoping to at least get an understanding of why it's behaving this way.

Comment: You can just publish without signing. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Publish without signing the ClickOnce app.